# Why does $DeploymentProcess.Steps.Name[0] return first if many, but first character of first if only one?

Tags: powershell

```
$ReleaseBody = @{
    Id = $Project.Id
    ProjectId = $Project.Id
    ChannelId = $Channels.Items.Id
    Version = $VERSION
    SelectedPackages = @( @{
        StepName = $DeploymentProcess.Steps.Name[0]
        Version = $dt.Items.Version
    })
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

I am querying an API that returns one or more StepName via `$DeploymentProcess`, I want to always select the first for my POST. The above works fine if there are multiple steps but not if there is only one. Thoughts?

Comment: `$DeploymentProcess.Steps.Name[0]` -> `@($DeploymentProcess.Steps.Name)[0]`

Comment: to expand on AnsgarWiechers comment - adding `@()` around the $Var makes it an array _even if it only has one item_. for an array, the `[$Index]` is an index into the array of objects. for a single item, the `[$Index]` is an index into the _value_ ... usually a string or `.ToString()` value.